# Pintrest-style board using Flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, widget, flutter-layout, hybrid-mobile-app

So I want to show a Pinterest style board in my app but without `StaggeredGridList`, but through the normal, Container and Row/Column widgets.

Here is an image:

[image]

So at first, I tried to use `Expanded` to make container with the higher height, take up the height and the other take up the width, but this approach doesn't work when you want pictures below each other. So please post your code as an answer below.

**My Code:**

```
          Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 15, bottom: 12),
                // parent container housing all other widgets
                child: Container(
                  height: 220,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      // both the pics and colours
                      Expanded(
                        child: Row( // row
                          children: [
                            // vertical pic
                            Container( // first child
                              width: 180, // give it a width, it takes up the height of parent since it is wrapped with an expanded widget
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    15.0,
                                  ),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: NetworkImage(storiesList[0]),
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill
                                  )
                              ),
                            ),

                            // spacing between vertical pic and horizontal pic
                            SizedBox( // second child
                              width: 12,
                            ),

                            // banner pic and colours
                            Expanded( // thrid child [consists a column with children ]
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  // banner pic
                                  Container(
                                    height: 165, // give it a height, it takes up the width of parent since it is wrapped with an expanded widget
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                          15.0,
                                        ),
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: NetworkImage(storiesList[1]),
                                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```

**Thanks a lot!!**

Comment: If this supposed to work as Pinterest, wouldn't it make sense to make all of the sizes dynamic, as they are coming from requests and you might not know the images' dimensions?

Comment: Can we do that in Flutter? I am sorry, I am just learning so I have no idea

Comment: There is no need to be sorry, that is what we are here for! And yes, you can handle http requests with [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/http). Furthermore, Pinterest has its own API, a way of making a bridge between their platform and your custom platform. I would highly recommend you to take a look at the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs). There, they explain a lot of things that can be useful for your idea. I see that you are heading on the right direction, but without a lot of crucial tools that will help you.

Comment: but I don't see any resources which allow me to use the Pinterest API in Flutter, can you give any resources (articles/documentation)

Comment: also, the content hosted in that design is not from Pinterest so I am not sure how the API will help

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. But since you mentioned "Pinterest-style", I though you wanted to make an app that included context from Pinterest. But since that is not your intent, I'll try to see what the problem is. By the way, is the image you posted the output of your app? If not, then I would appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220222/discussion-between-antonio-oliveira-and-calmante-c).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result using something like the [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package.

[image: output]

Your code should basically look like this:

```
StaggeredGrid.count(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  children: const [
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Tile(index: 0),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 1),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 2),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 3),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 4,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Tile(index: 4),
    ),
  ],
);
```